# How to run Diskpart in batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have Created Text file where it contains dispart commands and I run it from
The Batch File using the code below:

```dos
@echo off
Diskpart.exe /s D:\script.txt
```

Hopefully, That's works fine but there is something I don't want it to happen anymore and that was when Dispart.exe opened.It is openning  maximized.
So how to make it openning minimized?

Comment: So - you want it maximized or not?

Comment: OMG.I forgot but I have edited the question.I want it minimized

Comment: can you post an image of "maximized"? is it full screen? or just normal windows size? And what do you want it to do - open tottaly minimized?

Answer (score 0):

Use this command in your `.bat` file:

```
start /min diskpart
```

Hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: Nice MordechayS

Comment: It works fine the way I wanted it to but how if I want it to be completely

Comment: openning as hidden

Comment: @Matar Mudi - Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: @MatarMudi - What is "tottaly hidden"?

Comment: There is no way to run a cmd totally invisible using just batch. You will need PowerShell or VBScript or something. There are many posts on that on stackoverflow.